Multiple elements remain the same when targeting child elements of different parent divs using Selenium (Python)
I am trying to scrape data from listings on a real estate website and store the values (such as price, address etc...) within an object (one for each listing). I did this by first locating the all the parent div elements, storing them in a list, and then finding each individual child element while iterating through it.
I am not sure why, but for the last two elements, the values are the same across all objects (even though they are different on the website) likely meaning that Selenium is targeting the same element for all of them, even though I am trying to only target the child element of the current parent element in the iteration.
I tried searching for the XPATH I used within the chrome dev tools, and found that it located all the elements I am trying to target separetely, meaning that this (most likely) can't be due to the fact that there is a problem with my XPATH syntax.
No staleElement or other exceptions were raised.
WebDriverWait(driver, 10, ignored_exceptions=ignored_exceptions).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='list-item-content']")))
offer_listings = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='list-item-content']")

for offer in offer_listings: 
    address = offer.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//span[@class='address-part ng-binding']").text
    typology = offer.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//span[@translate='aantalMedebewonersLabel' or @ng-        if='::object.isZelfstandig']").text
    price = offer.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//span[@class='prijs ng-binding ng-scope']").text
        subsidy_possible = offer.find_element(By.XPATH, "./span[@ng-bind-html='::object.huurtoeslagVoorwaarde.localizedIconText']").text
    available_from = offer.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//span[@ng-if='::object.availableFromDate']").text
        available_until = offer.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//div[@class='header-informatie ng-binding ng-scope']").text 
        reactions = offer.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//span[@ng-if='object.numberOfReactions !== null']").text

I tried making my XPATH more specific, by adding multiple attributes and values for the elements I am having trouble targeting.
I was expecting that Selenium would only search for the XPATH within the parent div, but apparently that's not what it's doing as it wouldn't have the same values as elements from other listings.
**EDIT:
The full code illustrating how I plan on storing the data obtained.
I am using objects because down the line I want to implement methods
that will do something on a desired listing, as well as give me
the possibility of comparing it with other ones. I realise that I should have included this in my original post, but i was sure that it had something to do with XPATH or Selenium not properly locating the elements.
class Listing: 
    def __init__(self, address, typology, price, subsidy_possible, available_from, available_until, reactions):
        self.address = address
        self.typology = typology
        self.price = price
        self.subsidy_possible = subsidy_possible
        self.available_from = available_from
        self.available_until = available_until
        self.reactions = reactions

  
    def printInfo(self):
        #Print all the relevant info of the listing 
        print(" ")
        print("Address: " + self.address)
        print("Typology: " + self.typology)
        print("Price: " + self.price)
        print("Subsidy possible: " + self.subsidy_possible)
        print("Available from: " + self.available_from)
        print("Available until: " + available_until)
        print("Reactions: " + reactions)

potentialListings = []
WebDriverWait(driver, 10, ignored_exceptions=ignored_exceptions).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='list-item-content']")))
offer_listings = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='list-item-content']")

    for offer in offer_listings: 
        address = offer.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//span[@class='address-part ng-binding']").text
        typology = offer.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//span[@translate='aantalMedebewonersLabel' or @ng-        if='::object.isZelfstandig']").text
        price = offer.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//span[@class='prijs ng-binding ng-scope']").text
            subsidy_possible = offer.find_element(By.XPATH, "./span[@ng-bind-html='::object.huurtoeslagVoorwaarde.localizedIconText']").text
        available_from = offer.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//span[@ng-if='::object.availableFromDate']").text
            available_until = offer.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//div[@class='header-informatie ng-binding ng-scope']").text 
            reactions = offer.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//span[@ng-if='object.numberOfReactions !== null']").text
        
        globals()[f"listing{loop_iteration}"] = Listing(address, typology, price, subsidy_possible, available_from, available_until, reactions)
            potentialListings.append(globals()[f"listing{loop_iteration}"])
        loop_iteration += 1 
    

##Printing the listing information
for listing in potentialListings: 
    listing.printInfo()

When I do this, all the elements print their correct values, except for the last two (available_until, reactions). This is the output that results for those two:
Available until: PLEASE NOTE: TEMPORARY RENTAL UNTIL 12-08-2024!
Reactions: 47
Available until: PLEASE NOTE: TEMPORARY RENTAL UNTIL 12-08-2024!
Reactions: 47
Available until: PLEASE NOTE: TEMPORARY RENTAL UNTIL 12-08-2024!
Reactions: 47
However, when I try to print the values directly after locating them in the for loop, they give the correct values.

Do you mean that inside the for loop, all the values of available_until are the same, and all the values of reactions are the same?

@JohnGordon Yes, exactly. For all the other variables the values are unique to each listing.

@JeremySmith can you provide the HTML page source or URL to check

@LakshmanaraoSimhadri This is the URL:  https://www.room.nl/en/offerings/to-rent#?gesorteerd-op=prijs%2B&toekenning=3&locatie=Regio%2BAmsterdam

globals()[f"listing{loop_iteration}"] Why in the world are you doing it this way?

And loop_iteration is never updated, so f"listing{loop_iteration}" is always the same, so you're always overwriting the same global...

@JohnGordon I'm relatively new to programming, and I thought that having each object with a different name (Listing1, listing2, listing3) would make it easier to work with the values in the future.
I added a loop_iteration += 1 but it is indented in the stack overflow code.
Code would have likely been cleaner using enumerate and an index variable.

I added a loop_iteration += 1 but it is indented in the stack overflow code  Python doesn't let you just randomly indent code like that.  It should have been a syntax error.  Are you sure this is your real code?

@JohnGordon yeah, it probably got indented when I copied it into stack overflow and pressed command + k to format it as code.
Regardless, it works now, I found my mistake! I was printing the values without the .self in the object method...

Found my mistake:
def printInfo(self):
        #Print all the relevant info of the listing 
        print(" ")
        print("Address: " + self.address)
        print("Typology: " + self.typology)
        print("Price: " + self.price)
        print("Subsidy possible: " + self.subsidy_possible)
        print("Available from: " + self.available_from)
        print("Available until: " + available_until)
        print("Reactions: " + reactions)

Forgot the self. in the last two items...
